# How do I convert a cv::Mat to a cv::Rect

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, rect

I have an Image in a cv::Mat as a face, I need the whole image in a cv::Rect object
I couldn't find how it is done
That or , if possible ,creating the Rect from an image in my directory

Comment: Are the mat and the rect the same size?

Comment: Please compare http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Rect_ with http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat, then reword your question.

Answer (score 8):

you *don't* convert a cv::Mat to a cv::Rect.

you want the part of the image *inside* that Rect ?

```
Mat roi = Mat(img,rect);
```

will give you the cropped region

Comment: I meant , I need to get the whole content of Mat to a Rect ,the whole image

Comment: again, the whole image inside the rect ? that's it.

Answer (score 4):

cv::Mat can't directly give you a cv::Rect, but you can create your
own using the size() method of cv::Mat, and by assuming that the starting point of the cv::Rect is (0,0)

`cv::Mat image;
    // load your image into the cv::Mat
    ...
    // now create the cv::Rect from the cv::Mat
    cv::Rect rect = cv::Rect(0, 0, image.size().width, image.size().height);`

Comment: Another syntactic sugar way is `cv::Rect rect = cv::Rect(cv::Point(0, 0), image.size());`. For me personally, this constructor more logically groups the cv::Rect parts, i.e. anchor point and dimensions.

Comment: Why are you using `image.size().width` instead of `image.cols`?

Answer (score 2):

Although, as @berak says, you can't convert a cv::Mat to a cv::Rect, I am guessing you want something like this (untested).

```
cv::Mat face;   // you already have this with some data in it
cv::Mat image;  // you already have this with some data in it
cv::Rect rect(x, y, w, h); // some place in image where you want face

// copy face into rectange within image
cv::resize(face, image(rect), cv::Size(rect.width, rect.height));
```